# MAT 2003 Oxford Admissions Exam Question 5 Solution Verification

Tags: solution-verification

As ongoing trend, I have been solving old MAT past papers that do not have published solutions. I was wondering if anybody can verify my solution to the following question.
[image]

**My Solution**

**(i)** We prove this by contradiction. Suppose that after one second there is exactly one bulb ON. This implies that only two consecutive light bulbs say $n$ and $n+1$, must have had different  lights in the beginning. This implies that $n+3$ and $n+4$ had the same state since only one is ON after 1 second. Similarly, $n+4$ and $n+5$ must have had the same state and so on until we get that $n-1$ and $n$ have had the same state. This is a contradiction as $\text{state of } n \neq \text{state of } n+!$ and hence there could not be exactly one light bulb ON after one second.

**(ii)** Let $m$ be an odd number. Let there be $m$ many turned on lights after one second. Therefore, out of $N$ many lights m many consecutive pairs have different initial states. Let these pairs be

$$\{m_0,m_0 +1\},\{m_1,m_1 + 1\},\, ... , \{m_m, m_{m}+1\}$$

Say the initial state of $m_0$ is ON/OFF. By construction we will have, $m_0 +1, m_0 +2,\, ... ,m_1$ have the same initial signal. This implies that $m_2$ has a signal of ON/OFF. This can be done $m$ many times to show that $m_m$ is ON/OFF which implies that that $m_n +1, \, ..., m_0 -1$ are OFF/ON since $m$ is odd. This implies that $m_0 -1$ and $m_0$ have different initial values. This is a contradiction because if true this would imply that there are $m+1$ of these pairs. Thus there can not be odd many turned ON lights after the first second.

**(iii)** Let $b_n$ be the nth bulb. And let $v_i (b_n)$ be the status of the nth bulb after $i$ seconds have passed. The formula for $2$ seconds passed is
$$ v_2(b_n)
 \begin{cases} 
      \text{ON} & \text{if } v_1(b_n) \neq v_1(b_{n+2}) \\
     \text{OFF} & \text{if } v_1(b_n) = v_1(b_{n+2})
   \end{cases}
$$
The work of which I have done but I really can not put in LaTeX as it would take a lot of time. From the equation we see that it is only dependent on $b_n$ and $b_{n+2}$ as required.
**(iv)**

$$ v_4(b_n)
 \begin{cases} 
      \text{ON} & \text{if } v_1(b_n) \neq v_1(b_{n+4}) \\
     \text{OFF} & \text{if } v_1(b_n) = v_1(b_{n+4})
   \end{cases}$$
again the proof of which I have on paper but I really can not write in LaTeX due to time.

**(v)** After 8 seconds.

Comment: ii) Presumably you want $ m_0 < m_1  < \ldots m_m$? Even then, there isn't a contradiction (as you stated) if we had $m_0 = 1, m_m = n$, as it agrees with $m_0 -1$ and $m_0$ have different initial values. You need to be more careful with your language. v) You need to prove this statement, not just state the numerical answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin thank you for the comment. Yes I meant $m_0 < m_1 < \cdots <m_m$. I am not sure about your second comment as I am talking about pairs. For the last bit I have proven it but as I said previously, I really do not have the time to write it out on LaTeX as I have to write multiple questions here since there are absolutely no mark schemes for more than 10 papers, apologies for which.

Comment: ii) If $m_0 = 1, m_m = n$, then what is the contradiction? You're saying that "This implies $m_0-1 = n$ and $m_0=1$ have different initial values, but that's allowed since we have $m_m = n, m_m+1 = 1$ have different initial values.

Comment: iii, iv, v) We are not mind readers. If it's not written out, we cannot provide feedback on the solution. As currently written, you'd get partial credit. You may have a proof in your mind, but the difficulty of proof writing is in convincing someone else that your statements are indeed true.

Comment: @CalvinLin apologies for the unclarity. In future, I will aim to provide more of my workings (even if that means scanning pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very clean way to present the problem.

Denote a bulb to be OFF by 1.
Denote a bulb to be ON by -1.

Let $ S_t (i)$ denote the state of the bulb $i$ at time $t$.
From the definition, verify that $S_t (i) = \frac{ S_{t-1} (i)}{ S_{t-1} (i+1)} $.

i, ii) Observe that for $ t \geq 1$, $ \prod S_t (i) = \prod \frac{S_{t-1} (i) } { S_{t-1} (i+1) } = 1  = (1) ^{ \text{number of OFF} } (-1) ^ { \text{ number of ON} }$.
Hence, the number bulbs that are ON is even.

iii, iv, v) It can be easily proven (E.g. by induction) that $S_{2^t} (i)  = \frac{ S_0 (i) } { S_0 (i+2^t)}$, so the state at time $2^t$ only depends on $S_0 (i)$ and $S_0 (i+2^t)$.
Thus when $N= 2^t$, $S_N(i) = \frac{ S_0 (i) }{S_0 (i+N) } = 1$, so all bulbs are OFF.

Comment: Re: Your last line: If $N$ is odd and $t>0,$ not all bulbs can be on by Part ii...... Also, if $N=3$ and if exactly one bulb is on at $t=0$, then at any time $t>0$ there will be $2$ bulbs on and $1$ off.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Good points. The induction only works for $2^t$  and the state of 1 is OFF, not ON.

Comment: +1........ Suppiemental: The Q "How long does this take?" could mean "What is the least $t$ such that all bulbs are off at time $t$, regardless of the initial state?"  If $N$ is a power of $2$ then this least $t$ exists and is not more than $N$, but is it equal to $N$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes to your supplemental question. The idea is at time $t< N$, the state of bulb $i$ depends only on the states $S_0(i), S_0(i+1), \ldots S_(i+t)$. Also, by the fraction multiplication, it depends on an even number of states, and $ S_0(i)$ appears exactly once. So, we can toggle $S_t(i)$ (and also a lot of other states at time t) by toggling $S_0(i)$. This potentially breaks down at time $ t = N$ because of how the bulb loops around, and definitely breaks down when $N = 2^k$.